# Enforce Data-Driven 1:1 Constraint on 1:M Relationship

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-design

Using SQL Server 2K8 R2, I have two related tables - Member and Questionnaire. Each table has a BigInt PK called ID. Questionnaire has MemberID to relate back to the member who is in the process of completing the form. **Over time**, a member may complete the questionnaire many times. The business requirement is that each member complete a questionnaire **at most** once per year. AFAIK this can't be solved using a simple `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.

Is there is "clean" way to do this? I'm hoping to avoid doing something like the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Questionnaire_Insert
  ON Questionnaire
  INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS BEGIN
  -- Check for a violation of once questionnaire per calendar year and if found, call RAISERROR

  -- Otherwise continue with INSERT
END;
```

The reason I don't want to use this approach is primarily because it requires me (or whomever will be maintaining this solution in the long-term) to remember to maintain the trigger if the schema for Questionnaire should change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a unique index on the the questionnaire table that includes MemberId and year.

Comment: Hahahaha!! I could kick myself. See what happens when you're too close to the problem? Couldn't see the forest from the trees today. TYVM!